# Phaser - how to initialization all state in one time when i start game?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to initialization all state when I start my game, so any solution? Thanks.

I try this code :

```
this.state.add('LoadingState', this.loadingState);
this.state.add('GameState', this.gameState);
this.state.start('LoadingState');
```

But state just create when i start it

Comment: We're going to need more context here - what's wrong with the code you provided? What's calling it? How is your game started?

Comment: Phaser state have a create function, but when i add state. The create function is not call by phaser, The function 'create()'  of state just call when i start state. But I want initialization all state when my game start up, all state will be create when my game start up

Answer (score 0):

By default when loading new state you have the choice to clear world ( all group belong to old state ) and clear cache (all sprite, textures, audio, etc...)
By loading all of state is likely to switch between state with out clear world or cache.
You can do that by create a boot state, and push all of your other state 's preload, create into that boot state. And when start new state make sure to set clear world or cache to false. Since everything you want have been loaded already.